# ROS to LCM or ROS to APRIL Integration?

Tags: ros, integration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello answers,

Is anybody working on a general way of interfacing ROS with [LCM](http://code.google.com/p/lcm/) or [APRIL](http://april.eecs.umich.edu/)? There are some tools there I'd like to use. Doing it myself won't be too painful, but I figured I'd ask before I got too far in.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30266/ros-to-lcm-or-ros-to-april-integration?/) by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4119 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-04-04**:
I was right: it's not painful at all. If I get a chance, I'll write up a tutorial somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Mac, I am interested in a port of the [APRIL tag toolkit](http://april.eecs.umich.edu/wiki/index.php/April_Tags) to ROS, and was planning on doing it quick and easy using a rosjava wrapper without necessarily using LCM. If you've made some progress on interfacing LCM with ROS, do you think there might be a more generic way for me to set up a port?

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-07-09**:
Short answer: no. ROSJava is probably a better way. If this does get done, please please please do a release! I know of several interested people.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-08-16**:
@Mac: http://www.ros.org/wiki/april

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-08-16**:
I saw that on ros-users today. Awesome!